# NullInjectorError: No provider for "ConfigService"

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I have 2 modules *ConfigModule* and *LoginModule* each has a service *ConfigService* and *LoginService*.  The *LoginService* uses *ConfigService*

My *LoginModule*

```
 @NgModule({
   imports: [
     // Angular
     CommonModule,
     HttpClientModule,
     BrowserAnimationsModule,
     FormsModule,
     // Angular Material Flex Layout
     FlexLayoutModule,
     // Angular Material
     MatInputModule,
     MatButtonModule,
     MatIconModule
   ],
   declarations: [
     // Components
     LoginComponent,
     NewUserComponent,
     ForgotPasswordComponent,
     // Directives
     ForbiddenCharactersDirective,
     EquateDirective
   ],
   providers: [
     { // this will activate when you include this module
       provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
       useClass: AuthHttpInterceptor,
       multi: true
     },
     LoginService
   ],
   schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
   exports: [
     LoginComponent,
     NewUserComponent,
     ForgotPasswordComponent,
     ForbiddenCharactersDirective,
     EquateDirective
   ]
 })
```

My *ConfigModule*

```
 @NgModule({
   imports: [
     CommonModule,
     HttpClientModule
   ],
   providers: [
     ConfigService,
     {
       provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
       useFactory: initConfig,
       deps: [ConfigService],
       multi: true
     }
   ]
 })
```

*LoginService*'s constructor

```
 constructor(
   private _http: HttpClient,
   private _configSrvc: ConfigService // <==== Injected ConfigService
 ) {
  // get base url for api endpoints
  let api = this._configSrvc.get('api');
  if(api && (typeof api === 'string'))
    this.baseUrl = api;

  let endpoints = this._configSrvc.get('login.endpoints');
  if(endpoints)
    this._endpoints.endpoints = endpoints;
} // constructor
```

When I import both modules into my application module

```
 @NgModule({
   imports: [
     ...,
     ConfigModule,
     LoginModule
   ]
 })
```

and then try to run `ng serve` or `ng serve --preserve-symlinks` I get the following error

```
 AppComponent.html:2 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[LoginService -> ConfigService]: 
   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[LoginService -> ConfigService]: 
     NullInjectorError: No provider for ConfigService!
```

It is my understanding that a provider should be available to the whole application and it's other modules/components/etc if the provider is declared in the providers array of the imported module.

I don't understand why there is `No provider for ConfigService` for the *LoginService* ??

The only thing I can think of is some race situation is occurring where the *LoginService* is being instantiated either at the same time or before the *ConfigService* but how do I fix that if that is the culprit?

Comment: You need to import `ConfigModule` to your `LoginModule`, if you created a `SharedModule` (singleton) and imported to your `app.module` then that would be shared through out the whole application. In your case, `LoginModule` doesn't know anything about `ConfigModule`, due to module scope/separation.

Comment: Wouldn't importing the `ConfigModule` in the `LoginModule` create 2 instances of `ConfigService`?  I have other modules that would be using this service within the application I want there to be only one and have it available globally?

Comment: Which is why I mentioned `SharedModule` (singleton service). Here's the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services) from angular about it.

Comment: I'd suggest to provide a way to replicate the problem, because it isn't usual one and may be specific to your setup. Try https://stackblitz.com/ . Or if it doesn't work, post a github repo.